# Turn integer into money format while typing in an input box

Tags: javascript, integer, inputbox

I'm going to try and get this across as clearly as I can.

I need an input box  to read an integer, for example "12345" and turn it into a money format, example: $123.45. This needs to take place while the user is typing.

Comment: If it needs to be done while the user is typing, use js... so the question shouldn't be tagged PHP

Comment: All you need is all here : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/currency

Comment: Messing with the value while the user is typing is very annoying. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sorry about the PHP tag, I should have known. RobG, this is a personal project for myself, so I will be the only one messing with it for now. JSK NS I'm not so much fluent with javascript, am getting there, but I haven't tried much, I did try to research this and could not find anything. Thank you guy's for your input.

Answer (score 4):

I created a function to do it right away (on keydown) to get rid of the in-between value when you do it afterwards (keyup or blur). It follows the [Canadian format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) but you can easily change it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/93zgymx9/2/)

It doesn't work in IE < 9

```
$('.numberOnly').on('keydown', function(e){

  if(this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == 0){
    // selectionStart won't work in IE < 9

    var key = e.which;
    var prevDefault = true;

    var thouSep = " ";  // your seperator for thousands
    var deciSep = ",";  // your seperator for decimals
    var deciNumber = 2; // how many numbers after the comma

    var thouReg = new RegExp(thouSep,"g");
    var deciReg = new RegExp(deciSep,"g");

    function spaceCaretPos(val, cPos){
        /// get the right caret position without the spaces

        if(cPos > 0 && val.substring((cPos-1),cPos) == thouSep)
        cPos = cPos-1;

        if(val.substring(0,cPos).indexOf(thouSep) >= 0){
        cPos = cPos - val.substring(0,cPos).match(thouReg).length;
        }

        return cPos;
    }

    function spaceFormat(val, pos){
        /// add spaces for thousands

        if(val.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0){
            var comPos = val.indexOf(deciSep);
            var int = val.substring(0,comPos);
            var dec = val.substring(comPos);
        } else{
            var int = val;
            var dec = "";
        }
        var ret = [val, pos];

        if(int.length > 3){

            var newInt = "";
            var spaceIndex = int.length;

            while(spaceIndex > 3){
                spaceIndex = spaceIndex - 3;
                newInt = thouSep+int.substring(spaceIndex,spaceIndex+3)+newInt;
                if(pos > spaceIndex) pos++;
            }
            ret = [int.substring(0,spaceIndex) + newInt + dec, pos];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    $(this).on('keyup', function(ev){

        if(ev.which == 8){
            // reformat the thousands after backspace keyup

            var value = this.value;
            var caretPos = this.selectionStart;

            caretPos = spaceCaretPos(value, caretPos);
            value = value.replace(thouReg, '');

            var newValues = spaceFormat(value, caretPos);
            this.value = newValues[0];
            this.selectionStart = newValues[1];
            this.selectionEnd   = newValues[1];
        }
    });

    if((e.ctrlKey && (key == 65 || key == 67 || key == 86 || key == 88 || key == 89 || key == 90)) ||
       (e.shiftKey && key == 9)) // You don't want to disable your shortcuts!
        prevDefault = false;

    if((key < 37 || key > 40) && key != 8 && key != 9 && prevDefault){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey){

            var value = this.value;
            if((key > 95 && key < 106)||(key > 47 && key < 58) ||
              (deciNumber > 0 && (key == 110 || key == 188 || key == 190))){

                var keys = { // reformat the keyCode
                48: 0, 49: 1, 50: 2, 51: 3,  52: 4,  53: 5,  54: 6,  55: 7,  56: 8,  57: 9,
                96: 0, 97: 1, 98: 2, 99: 3, 100: 4, 101: 5, 102: 6, 103: 7, 104: 8, 105: 9,
                110: deciSep, 188: deciSep, 190: deciSep
                };

                var caretPos = this.selectionStart;
                var caretEnd = this.selectionEnd;

                if(caretPos != caretEnd) // remove selected text
                value = value.substring(0,caretPos) + value.substring(caretEnd);

                caretPos = spaceCaretPos(value, caretPos);

                value = value.replace(thouReg, '');

                var before = value.substring(0,caretPos);
                var after = value.substring(caretPos);
                var newPos = caretPos+1;

                if(keys[key] == deciSep && value.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0){
                    if(before.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0){ newPos--; }
                    before = before.replace(deciReg, '');
                    after = after.replace(deciReg, '');
                }
                var newValue = before + keys[key] + after;

                if(newValue.substring(0,1) == deciSep){
                    newValue = "0"+newValue;
                    newPos++;
                }

                while(newValue.length > 1 && 
                  newValue.substring(0,1) == "0" && newValue.substring(1,2) != deciSep){
                    newValue = newValue.substring(1);
                    newPos--;
                }

                if(newValue.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0){
                    var newLength = newValue.indexOf(deciSep)+deciNumber+1;
                    if(newValue.length > newLength){
                    newValue = newValue.substring(0,newLength);
                    }
                }

                newValues = spaceFormat(newValue, newPos);

                this.value = newValues[0];
                this.selectionStart = newValues[1];
                this.selectionEnd   = newValues[1];
            }
        }
    }

    $(this).on('blur', function(e){

        if(deciNumber > 0){
            var value = this.value;

            var noDec = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < deciNumber; i++)
            noDec += "0";

            if(value == "0"+deciSep+noDec)
            this.value = ""; //<-- put your default value here
            else
            if(value.length > 0){
                if(value.indexOf(deciSep) >= 0){
                    var newLength = value.indexOf(deciSep)+deciNumber+1;
                    if(value.length < newLength){
                    while(value.length < newLength){ value = value+"0"; }
                    this.value = value.substring(0,newLength);
                    }
                }
                else this.value = value + deciSep + noDec;
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<script>
function formatAsDollars(el) {
  el.value = '$' + el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'').replace(/(\d\d?)$/,'.$1');
}
<\script>

<input onkeyup="formatAsDollars(this);">
```

I find it really annoying, others will too.

Comment: Like I said, this is for me only. Also, it will not add the comma in the thousandths place like this: $1,235.41, but it is a great reference point, thank you!!